# Find this element in this website using Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, xpath

I have used Selenium in VBA to get to this page and would like to click on the 'WIP Management' Button. However the code that I use says the element is not found. Could someone please help.

This is the part of the website with the inspect panel

[image]

This is my code that can't find the element.

```
If obj.IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//button[text()='WIP Management']")) Then
    MsgBox "True"
Else
    MsgBox "False"
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not see the button `tag` in `HTML`, try the below `locator`

```
//*[text()='WIP Management']
```

**OR**

```
//*[contains(text(),'WIP Management')]
```

**OR**

```
//*[normalize-space()='WIP Management']
```

Comment: thank u so much 3rd one worked appreciate it big time.

Comment: @mdsyafiq - Please accept the answer if your issue is solved by the provided solution.